# Не отображаются новые элементы на странице

Tags: html, css

Всем привет! Написал вот такой код, при попытке добавить новый параграф/div, ничего не получается, текст с параграфа не отображается на странице. Можете помочь разобраться, в чем дело? Код внизу

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <style>
    #containertop {
      height: 90px;
      width : 1920;
      border: 1px solid #E6E6E6;
      margin: -10px;
    }

    #containericon {
      margin: -85px 800px;
    }

    body {
      background-color: #FFFFFF;
    }

    #erroryoutube {
      margin: 250px 575px;
      height: 500px
    }

    #aboutus {
      font-size: 30px;
      font-family: Comic sans ms;
      font-weight: bold;
    }

    #about1 {
      margin: -800px 550px;
    }

    #err {
      height: 400px;
      width: 700px;
    }

    </style>
</body>

<div id="containertop"></div>
<div id="containericon">
    <a href="https://www.youtube.com/">
        <img id="headericon "src="youtubeicon.png" alt="" id="headerimage">
    </a>
</div>

<div id="erroryoutube">
    <img id="err" src="erroryoutube.jpg" alt="">
</div>

<div id="about1">
    <p id="aboutus">Раскрутка каналов на Youtube, продвижение видео.</p>
</div>

</html>
```

Comment: в чем заключается "попытка добавить новый параграф/div"?

Comment: у вас все элементы вне `<body>`

Comment: "добавляю новый параграф и ввожу текст и сохраняю" - что это значит, известно только Вам

Comment: добавляете текст в редакторе, изменяя html файл?

Comment: Перенесите все блоки в  body

Comment: спасибо, помогло